# Clear drop down values after onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have my drop down with time values. I would like to reset my drop down if I click on my drop down. My current code gives me new set of values each time I click on my drop down. Also I tried to use .empty() but that did not work. Here is my HTML:

```
<td>
    <select name="stime" id="stime">
       <option value="0">--Select start time--</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
    $j('#stime').on('click', function() {
        //Populate start time dropdown with values 
        for(var i=700; i<= 1700; i+=15){
            var mins = i % 100;
            var hours = parseInt(i/100);

            if (mins > 45) {
                mins = 0;
                hours += 1;
                i = hours * 100;
            }

            var AmPm = " AM";
            //set hours 12 to PM
            if(hours == 12){
               AmPm = " PM";
            }

        //format all hours greater than to PM
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours = hours - 12;
            AmPm = " PM";
        }

        $j('#stime').children().not(":first").empty();

        //populate stime with values
        $j('#stime').append('<option value="'+('0' + (hours)).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + mins).slice(-2)+AmPm+'">'+('0' + (hours)).slice(-2)+':'+('0' + mins).slice(-2)+AmPm+' </option>');
    }    
 });
```

My current code gives me a blank drop down and I can see that scroll bar is getting smaller after each time I click on the drop box that tells me that values never were removed. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this right bellow the declaration of the function

`$("#stime option:gt(0)").remove();`

like

`$j('#stime').on('click', function() {
    $j("#stime option:gt(0)").remove();`

`...`

and remove this line

`$j('#stime').children().not(":first").empty();`

the line above is inside the for loop and it's making all items an empty string.

Comment: I tried this code, I'm getting correct values in my drop down but if I click on the option nothing happen. My drop down did not select clicked option.

Comment: because it's deleting and generating the values again every time you click on the dropdown.. you need to change the event according to what you want to do.

Comment: Is there any other approach for this?

Comment: just change the event to `focus` instead of `click`.. just remember that it will lose the selected value when you click again.

Comment: if the answer fixed the initial problem, please check as answered.